# spinner android

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

Есть выпадающий список:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> langadapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(context, R.layout.langdropdown, R.id.langtextview, learnlanguages);
langadapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.langdropdown);
Spinner langspinner = (Spinner)v.findViewById(R.id.tutorial0spin);
langspinner.setAdapter(langadapter);
```

langdropdown.xml:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/langimageview"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:id="@+id/langtextview"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textColor="@color/textongreen" />
```

В каждом пункте помимо текста есть картинка, которая для каждого элемента разная.
Как реализовать эти картинки?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно реализовать свой адаптер. Пример:

```
    public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter  {

        /** Массив с id ресурсов на картинки */
        private ArrayList<Integer> drawIDs = new ArrayList<>();

        private ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();

        private Context context;

        public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> strings, ArrayList<Integer> drawIDs) {
            super(context, R.layout.langdropdown, R.id.langtextview);
            this.drawIDs = drawIDs;
            this.strings = strings;
            this.context = context;

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return drawIDs.size();
        }

        /** Обработка spinner button (свернутой вьюхи). Если вид вьюхи такой же, 
            как у выпадающей, делать такую же обработку, как в методе getDropDownView. */
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
            ViewGroup row
                = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_button, parent, false);
            TextView text = (TextView) row.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            text.setText(strings.get(position));
            return row;
        }

        /** Обработка выпадающих элементов. */
        @Override
        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
            View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.langdropdown, parent, false);
            TextView langTextView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.langtextview);
            ImageView langImageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.langImageView);
            langTextView.setText(strings.get(position));
            langImageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,drawIDs.get(position);
            return row;
        }
```

Comment: Вы в месте объявления `ArrayList<>` потеряли угловые скобки `<>`. Здесь: `private ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList();` И поставили две `);` в самой последней строке.